# Plugin in Wordpress is automatically installed and activated

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a quite strange problem with a Wordpress site. I manage a few Wordpress sites but I never experienced this problem. A plugin gets automatically installed after few days. In addition it is a maintenance plugin, called Maintenance from Webfactoryltd. But every time I delete or just deactivate this plugin, it gets reactivated / installed again and switches to maintenance mode.

This is a premium site buyed on themeforest (flatsome), but I don't think it has something to do with the premium template.

I tried following things:

- Delete / Deactivate the plugin
- Deactivate all plugins and reactivate only needed ones (Woocommerce)
- Deactivate all caching plugins (Redis, WP Optimize)
- Deactivate the automatic updater in config.php
- Deactivate all automatic updates on the plugins itself
- Installed Crontrol (plugin) to maybe get a cronjob which is responsible for that

Nothing worked. Has someone an idea what I can try now? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you reviewed your server logs to understand how this plugin is continuously reinstalled and reactivated? Is this something proprietary your host is installing, for example? Are you seeing anything like vulnerability exploitation in your server logs? Have you taken a look at the code of the plug-in that keeps getting installed and reviewed it for anything obfuscated/malicious?

Comment: This plugin? https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2020-6167/

Comment: @Justinas Exactly this! Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

You can set limit file permission for .htaccess, wp-config.php for 444. Also, set recommended folder permissions.

You can install Wordfence & scan to see results where the file is affected & fixed it.

You can run also, virus scanner from the Cpanel account.

Answer (score 0):

My site was compromised. Thanks to the [link](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2020-6167) of Justinas I could take further steps to deal with this issue.

I could pinpoint the problem to a user (client) which I think run some scripts from it. The Wordfence Plugin helped with that a lot. I restricted the user and reset the password.

I also used Wordpress [FAQ - My Site was hacked](https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/)  for orientation in this case.

Especially thanks to @Justinas for the report.